# Optimal Solution: Get a random sample of items from a data set

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, performance

So I recently had this as an interview question and I was wondering what the optimal solution would be.  Code is in Objective-c.

Say we have a very large data set, and we want to get a random sample
of items from it for testing a new tool.  Rather than worry about the
specifics of accessing things, let's assume the system provides these
things:

```
// Return a random number from the set 0, 1, 2, ..., n-2, n-1.
int Rand(int n);

// Interface to implementations other people write.
@interface Dataset : NSObject

// YES when there is no more data.
- (BOOL)endOfData;

// Get the next element and move forward.
- (NSString*)getNext;

@end


// This function reads elements from |input| until the end, and
// returns an array of |k| randomly-selected elements.
- (NSArray*)getSamples:(unsigned)k from:(Dataset*)input
{
  // Describe how this works.
}
```

Edit:  So you are supposed to randomly select items from a given array.  So if k = 5, then I would want to randomly select 5 elements from the dataset and return an array of those items.  Each element in the dataset has to have an equal chance of getting selected.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to what your question is. Is it "Describe how it works" ?  Or what is the optimal solution of generating random numbers? or.. ?

Comment: Im assuming you can move through the dataset as many times as you wish (even though there is no reset routine on the Dataset object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good time to use [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). The following is an Objective-C adaptation for this use case:

```
NSMutableArray* result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:k];

int i,j;

for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    [result setObject:[input getNext] atIndexedSubscript:i];
}

for (i = k; ![input endOfData]; i++) {
    j = Rand(i);

    NSString* next = [input getNext];

    if (j < k) {
        [result setObject:next atIndexedSubscript:j];
    }
}

return result;
```

The code above is not the most efficient reservoir sampling algorithm because it generates a random number for every entry of the reservoir past the entry at index `k`. Slightly more complex algorithms exist under the general category "reservoir sampling". [This](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/vitter.pdf) is an interesting read on an algorithm named "Algorithm Z". I would be curious if people find newer literature on reservoir sampling, too, because this article was published in 1985.

Comment: I just found this article: http://gregable.com/2007/10/reservoir-sampling.html.  I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks. FYI, I edited the code slightly because you want to move on to the next element of the dataset in the second for loop whether use use the current element or not.

Comment: Sorry, but this code is brutally slow compared to other solutions.  If you want an optimal solution, this is **not** the answer.   It has to access every single member of the population and create a random number for each one of them.  What a waste!

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Well you have to do that anyway because you can't directly access each element.  The dataset is like a linked list: you have to walk through the whole list to get to the end.

Comment: I don't see any part of the question referring to a a linked list.  If that is the underlying structure, you do have to walk the list, but you **don't have to generate a random number for every element**.  That will slow and will exhaust the entropy of the PRNG.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, the first way:

```
1. use input parameter k to dynamically allocate an array of numbers
    unsigned * numsArray = (unsigned *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * k);

2. run a loop that gets k random numbers and stores them into the numsArray (must be careful here to check each new random to see if we have gotten it before, and if we have, get another random, etc...)

3. sort numsArray

4. run a loop beginning at the beginning of DataSet with your own incrementing counter dataCount and another counter numsCount both beginning at 0.  whenever dataCount is equal to numsArray[numsCount], grab the current data object and add it to your newly created random list then increment numsCount.

5. The loop in step 4 can end when either numsCount > k or when dataCount reaches the end of the dataset.

6. The only other step that may need to be added here is before any of this to use the next command of the object type to count how large the dataset is to be able to bound your random numbers and check to make sure k is less than or equal to that.
```

The 2nd way to do this would be to run through the actual list MULTIPLE times.

```
// one must assume that once we get to the end, we can start over within the set again
1. run a while loop that checks for endOfData
    a. count up a count variable that is initialized to 0

2. run a loop from 0 through k-1
    a. generate a random number that you constrain to the list size
    b. run a loop that moves through the dataset until it hits the rand element
    c. compare that element with all other elements in your new list to make sure it isnt already in your new list
    d. store the element into your new list
```

there may be ways to speed up the 2nd method by storing a current list location, that way if you generate a random that is past the current pointer you dont have to move through the whole list again to get back to element 0, then to the element you wish to retreive.

A potential 3rd way to do this might be to:

```
1. run a loop from 0 through k-1
    a. generate a random
    b. use the generated random as a skip count, move skip count objects through the list
    c. store the current item from the list into your new list
```

Problem with this 3rd method is without knowing how big the list is, you dont know how to constrain the random skip count.  Further, even if you did, chances are that it wouldnt truly look like a randomly grabbed subset that could easily reach the last element in the list as it would become statistically unlikely that you would ever reach the end element (i.e. not every element is given an equal shot of being select.)

Arguably the FASTEST way to do this is method 1, where you generate the random numerics first, then traverse the list only once (yes its actually twice, once to get the size of the dataset list then again to grab the random elements)

Answer (score 0):

Interessting question, but as there is no count or similar method in DataSet and you are not allowed to iterate more than once, i can only come up with this solution to get good random samples (no k > Datasize handling):

```
- (NSArray *)getSamples:(unsigned)k from:(Dataset*)input {
    NSMutableArray *source = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while(![input endOfData]) {
      [source addObject:[input getNext]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *ret = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:k];
    int count = [source count];
    while ([ret count] < k) {
        int index = Rand(count);
        [ret addObject:[source objectAtIndex:index]];
        [source removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        count--;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You need to increment a counter in your first while loop, otherwise it really isnt doing anything!!! You need that to return the size of the dataset, correct?  Also, this has no checking mechanisms to make sure your dont take the same element more than once.

Comment: @trumpetlicks the question states: "_Get_ _the_ _next_ _element_ _and_ _move_ _forward_" so no need to do that

Comment: the question doesnt state that, that is the only access method to get data, not a statement of the question!

Comment: @trumpetlicks and no, the second while loop only takes every element once, as i remove it after i have taken it. I do the first while loop to get random access to the data and dont have to hasle with `getNext` limitations.

Comment: The question doesn't say that you can't iterate more than once.  In my solution during my interview, I stored a pointer to the first element, looped over the data to get a count, then went back to the start.

Comment: with the interface given, you cant do that. I only use the Methods the Class has to offer. You can not take a pointer and assume you can do anything with it to get access  to the following objects.

Comment: If this is a really large list as the OP stated, then that is extremely memory inefficient, especially if the data objects are fairly large also.  I see what you are saying with your code above, but you will also (randomly) end up with an out of bounds access issue.  You initialize count prior to your loop, but you never update count after removing objects from your initial list.  there is quite a chance that after you remove some objects of accessing past your continuously shrinking version of the list.

Comment: I dont say its a good solution for other Classes, but the `DataSet` interface is very limited. And no, ther is only one thing my Method does not handle, and this is k > DataSet-length, and this is statet in the answer. You could add support for that but there is no discription for the correct behaviour in this case in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer I did in the interview but here is what I wish I had done:

1. Store pointer to first element in dataset
2. Loop over dataset to get count
3. Reset dataset to point at first element
4. Create NSMutableDictionary for storing random indexes
5. Do for loop from i=0 to i=k.  Each iteration, generate a random value, check if value exists in dictionary.  If it does, keep generating a random value until you get a fresh value.
6. Loop over dataset.  If the current index is within the dictionary, add it to a the array of random subset values.
7. Return array of random subsets.

Answer (score 0):

We need a little probability theory.  As others, I will ignore the case n < k.  The probability that the n'th item will be selected into the set of size k is just C(n-1, k-1) / C(n, k) where C is the binomial coefficient.  A bit of math says shows that this is just k/n.  For the rest, note that the selection of the n'th item is independent of all other selections.  In other words, "the past doesn't matter."

So an algorithm is:

```
S = set of up to k elements
n = 0
while not end of input
   v = next value
   n = n + 1
   if |S| < k add v to S
   else if random(0,1) >= k/n replace a randomly chosen element of S with v
```

I will let the coders code this one!  It's pretty trivial.  All you need is an array of size k and one pass over the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about efficiency (as your tags suggest) and the number of items in the population is known, **don't use reservior sampling**.  That would require you to loop through the entire data set and generate a random number for each.

Instead, pick five values ranges from *0* to *n-1*.  In the unlikely case, there is a duplicate among the five indexes, replace the duplicate with another random value.  Then use the five indexes to do a random-access lookup to the i-th element in the population.

This is simple.  It uses a minimum number of calls the random number generator.  And it accesses memory *only* for the relevant selections.

If you don't know the number of data elements in advance, you can loop-over the data once to get the population size and proceed as above.

If you aren't allow to iterate over the data more than once, use a chunked form of reservior sampling:  1) Choose the first five elements as the initial sample, each having a probability of 1/5th.   2) Read in a large chunk of data and choose five new samples from the new set (using only five calls to Rand).  3) Pairwise, decide whether to keep the new sample item or old sample element (with odds proportional the the probablities for each of the two sample groups).  4) Repeat until all the data has been read.

For example, assume there are 1000 data elements (but we don't know this in advance).

- Choose the first five as the initial sample:  current_sample = read(5); population=5.
- Read a chunk of *n* datapoints (perhaps n=200 in this example):

  - subpop = read(200);
  - m = len(subpop);
  - new_sample = choose(5, subpop);
  - loop-over the two samples pairwise:

    - for (a, b) in (current_sample and new_sample):  if random(0 to population + m) < population, then keep *a*, otherwise keep *b)
  - population += m
  - repeat

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the question. In the question, the number of entries in the data set is **not** known ahead of time. The set could be arbitrarily large, and I am sure that is why we are limited to `getNext` and `endOfData` methods for access. We have no idea what this `Dataset` class does, but we absolutely cannot count on knowing how many entries the input has.

Comment: Even if you can't know how many entries there are, straight reservoir sampling makes too many calls the random number generator.   A chunked version of reservoir sampling would do far better (i.e. read a large chunk of data, then update the sample).  Don't call Rand() for every entry because 1) it's slow and 2) it quickly drains all the entropy out of even the best pseudo-random-number-generator.

Comment: Right, that much is definitely true. Algorithm Z would be much faster because rather than choosing whether to include each element beyond element `k`, it chooses how many elements to skip before including another. Algorithm Z is still considered a reservoir sampling algorithm, though. I will update my answer to link to more literature.